# Issue with Substring function in C#

Tags: c#, substring

I am implementing a number conversion program from Visual Basic.Net to C #. This is the original code that converts a number from binary to hexadecimal.

```
Public Function BinToHex(ByVal BinStr As String) As String 
   Dim HexStr As String 
   HexStr = "" 
   Dim i As Integer 
   For i = 1 To Len(BinStr) Step 4 
       HexStr = HexStr & DecToHex(BinToDec(Mid(BinStr, i, 4))) 
   Next i 
   Return HexStr 
End Function
```

In C # I have the following code:

```
public string BinToHex(string BinStr) {
    string HexStr;
    HexStr = "";
    int i;
    var loopTo = BinStr.Length;
    for (i = 1; i <= loopTo; i +=4){
        HexStr = HexStr + DecToHex(BinToDec(BinStr.Substring((i - 1), 4)));
    }
    return HexStr;
}
```

This code makes use of the C#'s Substring function which, knowing that it is handled differently from Basic's mid function, we must subtract 1 from the variable that is used as the function's argument. But executing the function, for whatever value it receives, it throws the following error. The error poster is this:

[image: Substring function error poster with invalid parameters]

Comment: Please do not include code or errors as images. Copy the exception text and include it as text instead.

Comment: [_Convert.ToInt32(string, base)_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_System_Int32_) ?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the string has a length that is an even multiple of four? if not, you will get errors.

Answer (score 0):

As [substring docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) says, you can't extend the string length, so you have to check if `BinStr.Length % 4 == 0`